# Sort a dictionary of dictionaries on nested dictionary property

Tags: powershell, sorting, dictionary

Given an ordered dictionary that contains dictionaries of an arbitrary number of items, I need to sort on the value of one of those items.
So

```
$data = [Ordered]@{
    '1' = @{'thing' = "3"}
    '2' = @{'thing' = "2"}
    '3' = @{'thing' = "1"}
}
```

sorted on the value of `thing` would produce the same end result as

```
$ordered = [Ordered]@{
    '3' = @{'thing' = "1"}
    '2' = @{'thing' = "2"}
    '1' = @{'thing' = "3"}
}
```

I can sort the first dictionary on it's own keys using `.GetEnumerator()`, but I am stumped as to how I would sort based on the nested key's value, and yet still grab the item in the outermost dictionary to add to a new `[Ordered]`. I started with this

```
$data = [Ordered]@{
    '1' = @{'thing' = "3"}
    '2' = @{'thing' = "2"}
    '3' = @{'thing' = "1"}
}

$ordered = [ordered]@{}
foreach ($item in ($keyStatus.GetEnumerator() | Select-Object Value | Sort-Object -Property Value)) {
    $ordered[$item.Key] = $item.Value
}
```

but of course that errors at the foreach. I suspect this is going to be a late night face palm moment, but there it is.

And, for anyone, like myself, who prefers an example that makes sense, rather than a minimal example, the real data would look something more like this

```
$data = [Ordered]@{
    '{GUID}' = @{'DisplayName' = "Program A"; 'DisplayVersion' = '1.2'}
    '{GUID}' = @{'DisplayName' = "Program Z"; 'DisplayVersion' = '0.5'}
    '{GUID}' = @{'DisplayName' = "Program M"; 'DisplayVersion' = '3.4'}
}
```

where `{GUID}` would be different actual GUIDs, which is the way I want to structure the data. But I want to then present the data sorted by `DisplayName`.

Comment: You are aware that after sorting you will no longer have an ordered dictionary but a collection of dictionary entries right?

Comment: @santiago-squarzon Correct, so those entries will then need to be added to a final `$orderd` variable, that will also be `[Ordered]@{}`, which I will then use for output.

Comment: You can use a *calculated* expression based on each entry’s “thing” property as the sort key to order the entries by, and then use a foreach-object to assemble a new sorted (and ordered) dictionary - e.g. ```$data.GetEnumerator() | sort-object -property @{expression = { $_.Value.thing } } | foreach-object { $sorted = [ordered] @{} } { $sorted.Add( $_.Key, $_.Value ) }```. Your sorted values are now contained in ```$sorted```…

Comment: @mclayton OK, not sure I understand that yet. But it's working, so that gives me something to study. Having `$sorted = [ordered] @{}` inside the `foreach-object` is making my head hurt. I would think that would recreate the `$sorted` variable over and over.

Comment: ```{ $sorted = [ordered] @{} }``` is the ```-Begin``` parameter - it runs once before the first item is processed - it’s basically an initialiser. The second script block is the ```-Process``` parameter that runs for every item. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.2#-begin

Comment: Aha. I also had no idea that was possible, though I guess I should have. I am used to seeing the labels, but it makes sense to not require them  in a one liner that needs to be a little terse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in comments, after sorting, it will no longer be an [`OrderedDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary?view=net-7.0) but just a collection of [`DictionaryEntry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.dictionaryentry?view=net-6.0). If you want to reconstruct it you can follow this logic:

```
$data = [Ordered]@{
    [guid]::NewGuid() = @{'DisplayName' = "Program A"; 'DisplayVersion' = '1.2'}
    [guid]::NewGuid() = @{'DisplayName' = "Program Z"; 'DisplayVersion' = '0.5'}
    [guid]::NewGuid() = @{'DisplayName' = "Program M"; 'DisplayVersion' = '3.4'}
}

$newDict = [ordered]@{}

$data.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object { $data[$_.Key]['DisplayName'] } | ForEach-Object {
    $newDict[$_.Key] = $_.Value
}
```

Comment: That does hurt my head less. :) Maybe with coffee in the morning they will both make more sense. The multiple `[ ]` approach is new to me. Had no clue I could do that.

Comment: Also just verified that `ForEach-Object {$newDict.Add($_.Key, $_.Value)` also works. Which also makes my head hurt less. Never liked the idea of setting the value of a key that doesn't exist actually adds the key and sets the value. Syntactic sugar, I know, but somehow I just want to add. :)

Comment: @Gordon yeah both are valid ways to add key / value pairs. Tho, `.Add` will throw on an existing Key and `[...]` will just update the existing Key. So it's good to know how they work and when to use them